# grab selected image id and store them into array of ints

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have images rendered like this

```
<img id="9" class="thumb" src="/Content/uploads/Jellyfish.jpg">
<img id="10" class="thumb" src="/Content/uploads/Lighthouse.jpg">
<img id="11" class="thumb" src="/Content/uploads/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
```

Now I want to grab which photos are user click and sent that image id to the array which will later be sent to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Array push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). If you want it to have a toggled state, you can use a class to make a decision inside of the click handler.

```
var imgList = [];

$('img.thumb').click(function() {
    // Toggle the active class
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    // If the class just became active
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        // Get the image ID
        var imgId = $(this).attr('id');
        // Add the ID to your array
        imgList.push(imgId);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FHuhb/3/)**

Comment: great, is there a chance to recognize is element already clicked?

Comment: @panjo Please explain exactly what you mean. Do you want the items to only be clickable once? That is to say that once it is clicked, the event does not get triggered for that item anymore? Or do you want it to toggle like an on/off state?

Comment: on/off state would be exact desc. what I need.

Comment: @panjo Please see my updated answer and demo. It uses a class to prevent the event from occurring every other click. Essentially creating the on/off behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgs = array();

$('img').click(function(){
    imgs[] = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Should work.

**Edit:**

Sorry, there are some errors in my code, check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UPmKa/4/)**

Comment: Does the assignment to `imgs[]` add a new item to the array?

Comment: To be honest, it is in PHP and I'm pretty sure it's the same in JS. let me know if not :)

Comment: I only spend enough time doing JavaScript to be slightly dangerous ;-)